# Graph theory question, probably connected to Ramsey Theorem

Tags: graph-theory

Is the following statement true or false?

For every $n > 0$, such $N$ exists, that no matter how we "color" all of the subsets of the set with $N$ elements(we only use two colors), No matter how we color the subsets of the N-elemented set with two colors, we can always find an n-elemented subset, whose subsets have the same colour, sorry I wrote it wrong.

I am just confused how should I start this task, my guess is false, but I can't really begin anything. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Just to make it clear.  You color every subset - all $2^N$ of them.  Then you want to find $n$ subsets that all have the same color ?  Or $n$ individual elements that all have the same color ?  If so, what's the point of coloring subsets ?

Comment: No matter how we color the subsets of the N-elemented set with two colors, we can always find an n-elemented subset, whose subsets have the same colour, sorry I wrote it wrong.

Comment: Ok.  So you need to find a set $X$ of $n$ elements, such that all $2^n$ subsets of $X$ have the same color.  In particular, all one-element subsets of $X$ have the same color - so in fact all elements of $X$ must be the same color.  Does that sound right ?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false for all $n > 0$ because one can color the subsets according to the parity of their sizes, that is, if the size of the subset is odd, then color it blue, otherwise red.

Comment: Can you give me an example for $n=5$ please? :)

Comment: Color all $5$ singleton sets, all ${5\choose 3}$ $3$-subsets and $1$ $5$-subset blue and all the rest of the subsets red.